# Show divs based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

My radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase Only" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Sale Only" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase and Sale" />
```

Then my divs:

```
<div id="sale">
SALE!
</div>

<div id="purchase">
PURCHASE!
</div>
```

Finally my javascript at the moment:

```
<script>
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase and Sale") {
       $('#purchase').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#purchase').addClass("hidden");
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase Only" || $(this).val() == "Sale Only") {
       $('#purchase').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#purchase').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
</script>
```

How do I change it so the following occurs:

- When radio "Purchase only" is shown, only div id "purchase" is
  visible
- When radio "Sale only" is shown, only div id "sale" is
  visible
- When radio "Purchase and Sale" both div id "purchase" and
  "sale" are visible

Would someone please show me the best way of modifying my javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got your wires crossed a bit in your example. This should work:

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {

   if ($(this).val() == "Purchase Only") {
      $('#purchase').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#sale').addClass("hidden");
   }
   else if ($(this).val() == "Sale Only") {
      $('#sale').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#purchase').addClass("hidden");
   }
   else if ($(this).val() == "Purchase and Sale") {
      $('#sale').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#purchase').removeClass("hidden");
   }
});​
```

Here's a JS Fiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/yYBSV/1/

Comment: I'd change those to `else if`s after the first one to avoid looping through all cases unnecessarily.

Comment: Good answer otherwise. I'd upvote you if I had any more votes left today :)

Comment: I hate to do this, but when intergrated it doesnt seem to work. It doesnt seem to affect the divs, ive highlighted them in colours. Is it my implementation? http://goo.gl/PBvjR

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML-5** `data-attributes` to hold the corresponding ids'

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase Only" data-id="#purchase" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Sale Only" data-id="#sale" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase and Sale" 
                                               data-id="#purchase,#sale"  />

<div id="sale">
SALE!
</div>

<div id="purchase">
PURCHASE!
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(id).show();
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nSeag/1/)**
​

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to :

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    $('#sale, #purchase').removeClass("hidden");

    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase Only") {
       $('#sale').addClass("hidden");
    }
    if($(this).val() == "Sale Only") {
        $('#purchase').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/2meM5/ .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to modify your if/ else statment to get your code to work. Although I would recommend against using val() and plain text to do the detection. If you changed the html value the code would break. (it happens more often then you would think)

The solution should look something along the lines of this:

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "Purchase and Sale") {
   $('#purchase').show();
   $('#sale').show();
}else if ($(this).val() == "Sale Only") {
   $('#purchase').hide();
   $('#sale').show();
}else if ($(this).val() == "Purchase Only") {
   $('#purchase').show();
   $('#sale').hide();
}
});​
```